# How to assign a default value to field on Pojo codec error?

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I use the MongoDB java synchronous driver to work with my database, PojoCodecProvider is used to deserialize the PlayerData class, which stores player statistics. If some field of the class has changed their classes (for example, from String to int), or the Enum field has been deleted, then Pojo throws an exception and aborts the deserialization. How to prevent this and make the field get its default value in case of an error?

I use this codec registry:

```
CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
        MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                .automatic(true)
                .build()
);
```

I tried configuring codec registries and providers, but did not find the needed setting.